# Multiple errors in GraphQL kickstart

Tags: java, scala, graphql-java

I have a GraphQL API which is a facade to a REST service. The REST service can return multiple validation errors for its fields, and those errors have different types in my mapping.

Looking at GraphQL you are supposed to be able to return multiple errors for a given call, but I cant figure out how to do this with GQL kickstart. It seems to only be able to catch thrown exceptions rather than be able to set a list of GraphQLError instances which I need.

Am I going about this the wrong way? Is it possible to propagate multiple GraphQLError instances in GraphQL kickstart?

Comment: Same question. Did you resolved?

Comment: Unfortunately not. However I realized that returning multiple errors on queries is usually not necessary. Use the global exception handler for any runtime exceptional exceptions and use a payload type if you need to return other errors/non-successful conditions.

I also ended up ditching kickstart in favour of Netflix DGS which I like more.